# Angular change state instead of appending

Tags: angular

Changing state results in a strange behavior, the change gets appended to state instead of overwritting it.

When pressing on a certain date, I want the previous selection to disappear and highlight the current choice instead.

**calendar-day.component.html**

```
<div (click)="setClickedDay(day.date.getUTCDate())">
  <p>{{ dayNames[day.date.getDay()] }}</p>
  <p [ngClass]="setDayClass(day.date.getUTCDate())">{{ day.date.getDate() }}</p>
  <p>{{ day.quantity }}</p>
  <span [ngClass]="setDotClass()"></span>
</div>
```

calendar-day.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { CalendarDay } from 'src/app/models/CalendarDay'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar-day',
  templateUrl: './calendar-day.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar-day.component.scss'],
})
export class CalendarDayComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() day: CalendarDay

  dayNames: Array<String> = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
  clickedDay: number

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

      console.warn(this.clickedDay)

  }

  setDotClass(): object {
    let classes = {
      dot: true,
      redDot: this.day.isRejected,
      greenDot: this.day.isApproved,
      greyDot: !this.day.isRejected && this.day.isApproved,
      noDot: !this.day.tasksCount,
    }

    return classes
  }

  setDayClass(x:any): object {
    let currentDate = new Date()
    let classes = {
      selectedDay: x + 1 === this.clickedDay,
      today: this.day.date.getDate() === currentDate.getUTCDate(),
    }

    return classes
  }

  setClickedDay(x: any): void {
    if (this.clickedDay !== x + 1) {
      this.clickedDay = x + 1
    } else this.clickedDay = 0
    console.log(this.clickedDay)
  }
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-brook-l6kv3

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question. What have you tried so far? I don't see anything that's broken, I just see an unfinished component.

Comment: Yes, it's not broken, I just need to change clicked day state correctly. I want to allow the client to choose one day only, atm it allows all.

Comment: So I assume `<p>{{ dayNames[day.date.getDay()] }}</p>` appends new value instead of replacing old one?

Comment: it returns a string for the name of the day: 
dayNames: Array<String> = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

Comment: I understand that. You wrote `Changing state results in a strange behavior, the change gets appended to state instead of overwritting it.` - what do you exactly mean by that? Post your actual HTML output and expected HTML output.

Comment: At the moment: I click on any day, then click on another, both get highlighted.

What I want: I click on any day, then click on another, only the last clicked gets highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the behavior you looking for? what i see the behavior is strange because your `clickedDay` is managed `CalendarDayComponent` themselves, that is why when you click another the previous day still get highlighted. I think is better when your `CalendarDayComponent` is clicked and emit value to the parent and parent tell all child what day is clicked.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-almeida-qfqtf

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted.